# What are the disadvantages of using prometheus as business rule engine?

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules, prometheus

Is it a good idea to use prometheus as a business rule engine over drools.  What are the pros and cons associated with prometheus compared to drools.

Comment: Sounds like comparing a jackhammer and a chain saw.

Comment: I am an absolute beginner and i don't know whether i am going in right direction. I was asked to explore and posted this question as i was stuck for a long time.Any useful suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: As a beginner, you shouldn't be asked such questions. But you can tell the asker that these two - well, read my previous comment.

Comment: Drools and Prometheus have totally different use cases. You cannot use Prometheus as a rule engine. Prometheus is for to storing and analyzing time series metrics.

Answer (score 4):

The **cons** of using Prometheus as a business rules engine (as I see it).

- Data storage is currently ephemeral and non-durable - Long term storage of metric data is still a work in progress. Can you afford to lose the data you would be ingesting into Prometheus?
- Prometheus doesn't provide a dashboard solution - Prometheus' interface is intended for ad-hoc debugging. One would typically have to use another piece of software like Grafana for data visualisation.
- Logging - Prometheus is designed to collect and process metrics, not an event logging system. This may be an issue for you or the people using Prometheus when they want to track events rather than metrics.
- Not designed to handle sensitive data - Prometheus was created to handle operational metrics (cpu time, number of failed http requests, latency etc.). While dropping of labels to hide sensitive data is supported with relabelling, I'd imagine most data for business rules would fall on the side of being sensitive which would require lots of relabelling that would prove time consuming to implement.
- Prometheus is a tool made and used by people with an IT background - will your users who I'd assume don't have an IT background be equipped to work with such a tool?

So in theory you could use Prometheus for part of your business rule based system, but in practice you'd likely run into some if not all of the issues I have outlined above.

I'm not familiar with business rule based systems but I'd imagine they're better suited to the problem you're trying to solve than Prometheus.